# Excel VBA flashing image / text boxes - selective screen update?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a football manager game in Excel - just for a vba / Excel training exercise.

It's nearly finished, but the match screen flashes every iteration (each half minute that passes). I have played around with screen updating but still get the same problem, as I need the screen to update once every iteration to show time has passed, the game stats have changed etc.

a) The worksheet is fine, but the main screen image flashes (big issue), as do the text boxes (minor issue). If I just use a background image it doesn't flash but lacks the same visual effect.

b) the flash seems random - i.e. sometimes you'll go a whole 90 minutes without it flashing at all - other times it flashes like crazy and drives you mad.

Any suggestions?

I won't paste the whole code because its pretty huge.

Comment: It's likely that your code is taking long enough that you're interfering with the form repainting.  It'll be next to impossible to determine where the issue is coming from without seeing the code, but you may want to try some well-placed DoEvents calls to allow the application to repaint.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply. I've found a solution that works. I took a high res screen print of the image object over the background, cropped it and set the new image as a background. It looks identical and it no longer flashes :0-).